# Android - Bigger view when tapping marker infoview

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

i am trying to figure out how to get this view when tapping the infowindow of the marker. Does anyone have a clue how? I am geting the info for each marker from a database. Here is the link to an image of what im trying to achieve. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9pBS.png

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my app. I use a relative layout as parent. Map fragment and another relative layout for additional info are nested in it. When the marker is clicked, I change the visibility of my additional info layout to visible and set the data from my DB. When the user clicks the back button or another spot on the map I set it's visibility to invisible. Pretty simple actually.